# Incorrect output after converting to SqlDate

Tags: java, sql, oracle

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        String dateInString = "2016-04-23";

        try {

            Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
            java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
            System.out.println("Date: -- "+date);
            System.out.println("FormatterDate : -- "+formatter.format(date));
            System.out.println("SQLDATE : -- "+sqlDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Output :

```
Date: -- Sat Jan 23 00:04:00 CST 2016
FormatterDate : -- 2016-04-23
SQLDATE : -- 2016-01-23
```

**My out put should be 2016-04-23 not 2016-01-23**

Comment: From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) *"m | Minute in hour | Number | 30"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the javadocs

```
m   Minute in hour
```

You want

```
M   Month in year
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly note that [`mm`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) stands for Minute and not Month. For month you have to use `MM` instead.